# PHP Get duplicate values in array and average second value

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, average

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$ratingsInPosts = array
        (
        array("1",3),
        array("2",5),
        array("2",2),
        array("5",2),
        array("90",1),
        array("5",6),
        array("2",2),
        );
```

I Want to find duplicate values in the first column and avarage its values from the second column.

So that this`("1",3),("2",5),("2",2),("5",2),("90",1),("5",6),("2",2)`

ends up like this `("1",3),("2",3),("5",4),("90",1)`

Comment: Why `("2",3)` ?

Comment: in continuation to @revo 's comment, it should be (4+2+2)/3 = 8/3 and not 3.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit the first record so that its 5 instead of 4. So (5+2+2)/3 = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tested solution
I got the required Output

```
$ratingsInPosts = array
        (
        array("1",3),
        array("2",5),
        array("2",2),
        array("5",2),
        array("90",1),
        array("5",6),
        array("2",2),
        );
$arr1 = array_column($ratingsInPosts, 0);
$p = array_count_values($arr1);
foreach($p as $key => $value)
{
  $sum = 0;
  for($i=0; $i < $value; $i++)
  {
    $pos = array_search($key, $arr1);
    $sum += $ratingsInPosts[$pos][1];
    unset($arr1[$pos]);
    unset($ratingsInPosts[$pos]);
  }
  $re[] = array('"'.$key.'"',$sum/$value);
}
print_r($re);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you:

```
$groups = array();
// in this loop we group values by first column
foreach ($ratingsInPosts as $row) {
    $key = $row[0];
    if (!isset($groups[$key]) {
        $groups[$key] = array();
    }
    $groups[$key][] = $row[1];
}
$result = array();
foreach ($groups as $key => $value) {
    $avg = array_sum($value) / count($value);
    $row = array($key, $avg);
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$ratingsInPosts = array(array("1",3),array("2",5),array("2",2),array("5",2),array("90",1),array("5",6),array("2",2));


$result = array();    
$output = array();    
foreach($ratingsInPosts as $array){  
  $result[$array[0]][] = $array[1];
}
foreach($result as $key=>$array){
  $output[] = array($key,round(array_sum($array)/count($array)));
}


var_export($output);
?>
```